# int() causing overwrite of argument

Tags: c++, arrays, int

This is probably something fairly simple I'm missing, but could someone explain what's going on with my code here?

I'd expect `arrayone[0]` to be unchanged, as I'm never reassigning to it, but somewhere, it's being changed from `3` to `1`.

```
int arrayone[1];
int arraytwo[1];
arrayone[0]=3;
cout << "expected: 3\n";
cout << arrayone[0] << "\n";
arraytwo[0] = int(arrayone[0]/4.0); //int (5/4) = 0
cout << "expected: 3 0\n";
cout << arrayone[0] << " " << arraytwo[0] << "\n";
arraytwo[1] = int(arrayone[0]/2.0); //int (3/2) = 1
cout << "expected: 3 0 1\n";
cout << arrayone[0] << " " << arraytwo[0] << " " << arraytwo[1] <<"\n";
```

(that final line is returning `1 0 1` instead of `3 0 1`)

I've tried testing a few things, looking at where it gets changed; and I think it has to do with the int() function, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `arraytwo[1]`, which is *out of bounds*. Because of that you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Perhaps you meant to define `arraytwo` as an array of *two* elements:

```
int arraytwo[2];
```

The casting you do with `int()` have nothing to do with it.

---

On a note related to the casting: If you want an integer after the division, why not do integer division to start with? As in

```
arraytwo[0] = arrayone[0] / 4;
```

Comment: Of course. It's been a while since I learnt the language, and was remembering that arrays start from 0, and thus assumed array[1] had elements 0 and 1. That's obviously where my error lies. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `arraytwo` with a size of two, i.e., elements 0 and 1, like this

```
int arraytwo[2];
```

You don't say what toolchain you are using, but this is the sort of thing that both static and dynamic analysis will detect (for example clang static analyzer and sanitizer respectively).

Comment: Indeed, thanks. I'm just getting back into the language after a long break, and made an incorrect assumption about declaring an array *of length l* vs *with final element l*.

Regarding toolchain, I'm simply using the standard commandline compiler installed by default on the Raspberry Pi (c++); so it doesn't do very clever checking. I'm a little surprised it doesn't pick up on something as obvious as a statically defined out-of-bounds array, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
arraytwo[1] = int(arrayone[0]/2.0); //int (3/2) = 1
```

Here you are writing to an area beyond `arraytwo` (it has size 1, so you can only write to arraytwo[0]). That's undefined behavior - what happens in practice is that it's writing to the calculated position anyway, and that's the memory where `arrayone` is (at least on your setup, it depends on the machine, the compiler used and many settings). This is called memory corruption, and depending on the magnitude of the error you could even get a stack corruption, or, of course, a segmentation fault.

To prevent such mistakes, most compilers will issue a warning on this line. If this isn't happening for you, try looking into whether you can configure your compiler to be more strict with warnings.